# Okta SAML SpEL expression syntax

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, spring-el

I'm trying to configure Intelex with our enterprise Okta but I cannot get this simple expression to get accepted:

ALPH${""}${f:substringBefore(user.login,"@")}

Here is a sample username: APLH\1234

I tried using single quotes and double slashes (for escaping) and also asked ChatGPT for suggestions but Okta doesn't accept any.

I can't find an online editor/validator for SpEL either. Please suggest a correct acceptable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about attributes/username expression in Okta, then it's

```
'ALPH\' + String.substringBefore(user.login, '@')
```

[image]